# Rails routes match full hostname with multiple period in between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, special-characters

I'm trying to match a URL something like

```
http://example.com/this.is.my.full.hostname/something/else
```

apparently when I pass the param in the routes.rb file it doesn't recognize this parameter

my code says the following

```
match '/:computer_hostname/somethingelse' => 'test#info'
```

any ideas what's the right way to achieve the URL I wanted above ? Or is it even possible ? I know period is allowed character in URL but does it allow more than one ?

Comment: Do you want it to always look exactly like this? Or can it look something like this too? `http://example.com/this.is.my.full.hostname/something/else/and/this/and/that`?

Comment: @Dex does it matter ? I think the issue is, I need to set :computer_hostname => "some regular expression"

Comment: It may matter since it could make the regular expression more complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `constraints` method/option will help you out. Try something like the following:

```
match ':hostname/something/else' => 'test#info',
  :constraints => {:hostname => /[A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+/}
```

If you're doing multiple matches all with the same `:hostname` segment, then you can wrap them in a constraints method call:

```
constraints(:hostname => /[A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+/) do
  match ':hostname/something/else' => 'test#info'
  match ':hostname/foo/bar'        => 'test#foo'
end
```

Comment: Don't forget the missing bracket. Instead of matching `/something/else` you could also use a glob operator and change it to `match ':hostname/*something_else'` and this would store the rest to `params[:something_else]`