# Routes Error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I already have this in my routes file:

```
namespace :api do
    root :to => 'graphs#index' #default page when accessing /admin
    resources :graphs, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }

    match ':graphs/:id(/:method)'
  end
```

But when I try to open:

```
mydomain.com/api
```

or

```
mydomain.com/api/graphs/
```

I got the following error:

```
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:171:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:72:in `normalize_options!'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:55:in `initialize'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:272:in `new'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:272:in `match'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1173:in `match'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1360:in `match'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/routes.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in `block in namespace'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:546:in `scope'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in `namespace'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1119:in `namespace'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/routes.rb:80:in `block in <top (required)>'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `draw'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-06T23:12:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-07-06T23:12:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Did you run `rake routes` to see your route maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I'm not that familiar with the match statement, but it looks like you are missing the second part of it, like:

```
match ':graphs/:id(/:method)' => 'pages#something'
```

As I see here:

[Rails routes match full hostname with multiple period in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065955/rails-routes-match-full-hostname-with-multiple-period-in-between)

and here:

[understanding rails routes: match vs root in routes.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733101/understanding-rails-routes-match-vs-root-in-routes-rb)

Here's a [similar](http://asheepapart.blogspot.com/2010/07/mapperrb143in-defaultcontrollerandactio.html) issue where the action in the "to" was not properly stated.

Comment: Do you suggest me to use something else instead of match? And what if I want to do something like that: match ':graphs/:id(/:method)' => 'pages#:methodFromUrl'

Comment: I think there's an example here - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html - such as match ':controller/:action/:id/with_user/:user_id'
This route would respond to paths such as /photos/show/1/with_user/2. In this case, params would be { :controller => “photos”, :action => “show”, :id => “1”, :user_id => “2” }.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue within RESTful route.

Here is example:

```
    resources :categories do
      member do
        post 'sort/:move', constraints: { move: /up|down/ }
      end
    end
```

Requesting "/categories/1/sort/up" causes same error.

As you can see presence of :move parameter misleads rails which controller/action use.
So you need to specify "action" option explicitly:

```
    post 'sort/:move', constraints: { move: /up|down/ }, action: 'sort'
```

Note if use "to" option you cannot omit controller name:

```
    post 'sort/:move', constraints: { move: /up|down/ }, to: 'categories#sort'
```